# Using a pattern match in a makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with rules that look like this:

```
data/foo-trunk.xml:
    svn log -v --xml http://www.example.com/svn/foo/trunk > $@

data/bar-trunk.xml:
    svn log -v --xml http://www.example.com/svn/bar/trunk > $@

data/baz-trunk.xml:
    svn log -v --xml http://www.example.com/svn/baz/trunk > $@
```

How could I abstract this into a rule? For example, is there a way to do something like this (i.e., what would replace the ???)

```
data/%-trunk.xml:
    svn log -v --xml http://www.example.com/svn/???/trunk > $@
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming GNU Make, `???` should be `$*`.